# How use Nodejs Localstorage (scratch) with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

So I have a stored a token in a file "scratch" inside the assets of angular. I would like to use it in SpotifyService ti finally be authenticated but I dont know how angular can search my file and use it as a token:

Node Js

```
if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) {
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./src/assets/scratch');
```

}

...

```
app.get('/auth/spotify/callback',
    passport.authenticate('spotify',{failureRedirect:'/auth/error'}),
    function(req,res){
        const monToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
        res.redirect('/');
```

})

Angular

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {} from 'rxjs';
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SpotifyService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient,private jwt:JwtHelperService) { 
  }

  
  isAuthenticated() : Boolean { 
    let token=localStorage.getItem('token');
    return (token != null &&  !this.jwt.isTokenExpired(token));
  }


  setTokenHeader(){
    let devant: HttpHeaders=new HttpHeaders();
    //devant.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let authToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
    devant.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);
    return devant;
  }

  private header: HttpHeaders = this.setTokenHeader();
```

Basically, I don't know how can I use the file 'token' inside. If there's another method to store the token in the API please wirte it bellow

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it all wrong...
why do you wanna store the token in nodejs local storage...?
you don't have to store it just verify the token is valid or not which is passed from the cliend who has saved it

Comment: Isn't it the only way to "link" the backend with the front? Should I use JwtHelperService in the service?